# How to allow only first punctuation mark in string with different marks sequence between words

Tags: c#, regex, string, text, punctuation

If I need to allow only first punctuation mark in string with different punctuation marks sequence between words, for example if string is:

```
string str = "hello,.,.,.world.,.?,.";
```

in result I want get this:

```
hello, world.
```

It would be good to know both, how to pass such string after insert and how to avoid writing of more then one mark and one white space between the words in string directly in textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: `(?<=[,.])[,.?]+`.

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/di5Ebw/1.

If you need to have a list of special ponctuation that you want to strip we can adjust in `[,.]`!

(So in the example I give you the match is on the chars you want to remove: just replace that match with empty string - as you can see in the SUBSTITUTION panel at the bottom)

---

**[EDIT]** Extend the match cases.

If you don't want to bother let this do it for you: `(?<=\W)(?<! )\W+`

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/di5Ebw/2

Comment: yes exactly if I want figure out with punctuation separeted by white-space between words this way is useful

Answer (score 0):

.Net regular expressions have a punctuation class, so a simple way of achieving the required result is to search for the string `(\w\p{P})\p{P}+` and replace with `$1`.

For a regular expression that handles exactly the few punctuation characters used in the question the regular expression `(\w[.,?])[.,?]+` can be used.

(Note, the above shows the regular expressions. Their C# strings are `"(\\w\\p{P})\\p{P}+"` and `"(\\w[.,?])[.,?]+"`.)

Explanation. This looks for a word character (`\w`) followed by one punctuation character and it captures these two characters. Any immediately following punctuation characters are matched by the `\p{P}+`. The whole match is replace by the capture.

The `\p{name}` construct is [defined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#character_classes) as *"Matches any single character in the Unicode general category or named block specified by name.
"*.

The `\p{P}` category is [defined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) as *"All punctuation characters"*. There are also several subcategories of punctuation, but it may be best to look at [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/) to understand them.

Comment: this way is also useful, but in my case I've to figure out with punctuation separated with white-space between words